# Angular. Переопределяет ли forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders уже определённые в модуле провайдеры?

Tags: angular, модули

Переопределит ли объект, возвращаемый в методе forRoot() провайдеры, определённые в модуле и там будет лишь один провайдер — BASE_URL? Или в объекте, возвращаемом в forRoot() будут два провайдера: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS и BASE_URL?

```
@NgModule({
      providers: [
        {
          provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
          useClass: AuthInterceptor,
          multi: true
        },
      ],
    })
    export class SharedModule {
      public static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders<SharedModule> {
        return {
          ngModule: SharedModule,
          providers: [
            AuthGuard,
            {
              provide: BASE_URL,
              useValue: environment.baseUrl,
            },
          ]
        };
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Я выяснил, что при импорте объекта, возвращаемом в forRoot() не происходит переопределение провайдеров исходного модуля. Можете увидеть это здесь: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h1ftna?file=src/app/hello.component.ts